# oracle linux vm install: port 1521 provided for this listener is currently in use

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g, port

I am having issues installing oracle 11g R2 on my linux virtual machine.  I am doing this for school so am a beginner at this stuff.  The instructor tells us run ifconfig
 and then run cat /etc/hosts.
First of all he says that our output should look like the following:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:88:22:36
      inet addr:192.168.1.57  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
:       


[root@OraLinux ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.1.57  oralinux oralinux.localdomain
```

here the IP addresses match.

Mine looks like this:

```
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:B2:E2:A9
      inet addr:192.168.102.129  Bcast:192.168.102.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:feb2:e2a9/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:10247 (10.0 KiB)  TX bytes:2250 (2.1 KiB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:11488 (11.2 KiB)  TX bytes:11488 (11.2 KiB)
[oracle@OraLinux ~]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.153.131   oralinux oralinux.localdomain**
```

he then says if the IP addresses don't match run netca and add the port listner on 1521. 
When I try to do this netca throws me a message saying that port 1521 is already in use and that I cannot configure properly until I resolve the issue.  Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered and solve this problem today..

Turns out the solution is:

1) Your ethernet adapter IP address must match with the one you configured in /etc/hosts

2) Your system/VM must be connected to LAN

Otherwise, it will say 1521 is being used.
Hope it helped. Cheers.

Comment: I had to enter the fully qualified domain name, not just the host name here

Answer (score 1):

check the hosts ip,if the hosts ip is not right, it will also cause the listener's problem.

In my case, I check the ip fistly, ifconfig -a, and then change hosts following:

```
[root@oracle-one ~]# vi /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.56.101 oracle-one
```

Comment: I had to enter the fully qualified domain name, not just the host name here

Answer (score 0):

You are probably already running Oracle Listener on this port - 1521. Run `ifconfig -a` to see all network interfaces. `lsnrctl status` to see default listener status - is it running, what port, etc. You need to find what ip addresses your computer has assigned with `ifconfig` and create a listener that will listen on this network interface.

Answer (score 0):

Something else might be using port 1521. Try `netstat -ntap | grep 1521` to find out what it is (you need to be root for this to work).

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was log in as root and move to the etc directory.  From there I made a copy of the hosts file and changed the original file so that the ip address matched the address I received when I performed the ifconfig in Konsole.  Thank you all for the help.